# Why not wait for the river

Tags: rules

Watched a WPT final on TV. Final head-to-head, Player A holds As5c. Player B holds 2c2s. Player A goes all-in; Player B calls. The flop throws up an Ace, 8 and 9. The turn throws up a 2. Both players immediately stand up and shake hands, and commentators say "game over". But why? Couldn't the river have brought up a third Ace?

Answer (score 6):

if a third ace came, player B would have a full house (222AA) and player A would have 3 of a kind (AAA89). No matter what card comes, player B wins.